# Any way to replace a char* string with substring at the compile stage?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, constexpr

What I want to do is replace a string with constexpr function like:

```
constexpr auto replace_sub_str(const char* x) {
  // some magic
  
  return ans;
}

#define LOG(x) replace_sub_str(x)
```

example:
`LOG("hello XX, XX");`
this would be replaced as `"hello KK, KK"`

I updated the question since maybe the strange characters make people confused.. here `XX` just a substring, so is `KK`.

Comment: What's %% %%? Can you be more clear with example of what you want? You can use stringify operator # in macro but you have to do it in macro itself, not through a function. Note that `"Hello, world!"` and `"Hello, " "world!"` (note the space) are both legal string literals.

Comment: Why would you want to write `LOG("hello {}, {}")` instead of `"hello %%, %%"`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
template <auto N>
constexpr auto replace_sub_str(char const (&src)[N]) {
   std::array<char, N> res = {}; 
   // do whatever string manipulation you want in res.
   return res;
}


auto constexpr str = replace_sub_str("hello {}, {}");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my compiler told me the return ```auto constexpr str```  should not be ```constexpr ```, is it possible to return a ```auto constexpr str``` result?

Comment: @shoujiangma Then you probably broke `replace_sub_str` or called it with something not a constexpr. Show your code.

Comment: @shoujiangma please share your code so we can comment on it.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow  Thank you guys! https://godbolt.org/z/7oYv4Mj86

Comment: @shoujiangma please see https://godbolt.org/z/WY5WGsv59

Comment: @shoujiangma Looks like the compiler can't see that the array is fully initialized and that would be UB and not allowed in a constexpr. So just initialize it: `std::array<char, N> res{};`

Comment: Thanks Ayxan and @GoswinvonBrederlow , you guys are all genius!